# Edit header information of a DICOM file and export it again

Tags: export, import, image, metadata, headers-footers

I have some DICOM files and want to edit a part of the Header and export the DICOM files with this edited header.

I know how to Import a DICOM files and extract the Header Information, but how to edit it and subsequently export the DICOM again?

Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

1. Import the data and header.

[image]

2. Modify the header and export the file.

[image]

3. Your new Dicom file is ready. Good luck!